# Can I add an app launcher (optimally Slingshot) to the Dock?

Tags: plank, slingshot

Is there any way to add a launcher to the dock (optimally Slingshot, but any launcher would be great)?  It seems odd to me as a matter of design and efficiency to have to go to two different locations to launch applications. A single location in the dock would be great -- either as an option or as the default.

Comment: Could you please comment on my answer if the solution doesn't work for you or accept it if it does.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Cardapio - I think it's in the repositories, so type `sudo apt-get install Cardapio`.

Then find Cardapio in slingshot and add it to Plank. I know it's not slingshot, but it works just as well, although you may need to use Menu Editor and hide some of the unnecessary entries.

Personally I use DockBarX with Cardapio, but before that I used Plank so I can tell you it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Synapse

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:synapse-core/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install synapse
```

[Installation & demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rg2YBhl7Zhg)

Also if you want, you can remove slingshot entirely:
`sudo apt remove slingshot-launcher`

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't see in the Synapse demo how you can put it in Plank.  Is that possible?   If I wasn't clear in the OP, apologies.  But the goal is to add something like Slingshot to the Plank dock, so that you click that single icon and a selection of available applications opens.  Cairo-dock has something like this, as does Ubuntu (obviously).

Comment: @xmbwd yes, just like any other application. Run Synapse, it should appear in the dock, then right click on the icon and check "Keep in the dock"

Comment: Dear Dowvoter. It would be really nice if you (or someone else) could explain what is wrong with this answer. It's the most optimal solution to the problem as far as I can see.

Comment: A problem with the answer would be if Synapse would not show if already started in background when  when clicking its dock icon (I don't have it installed.) If it shows, your answer stands. And that is the case I think. But there is a second problem, Synapse is not exactly like the Slingshot, as you cannot select only with the mouse, but have to type.

Comment: @Rsync - `how you can put it in Plank. Is that possible?` - you can also drag and drop launchers/icons from the Slingshot lists onto the dock, and also from `usr/share/applications`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing this via a sh script, then create a .desktop file as a launcher to add to plank. I've never done it myself, but that's where I would start

In scratch create a new file:

```
!#/bin/bash

wingpanel --toggle-indicator app-launcher
```

save the file as launcher.sh or whatever.

run:

```
chmod +x launcher.sh
```

...to make the sh executable.

Then create your desktop file and save it to ~/.loca/share/applications or for all users /usr/share/applications. Make sure the file has a .desktop extension, e.g, launcher.desktop.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=App Launcher
Comment=Wingpanel Plank Launcher
Exec=/path/to/launcher.sh
Icon=/path/to/icon
Categories=Utility
Terminal=false
```

I've never done this myself, but it's a place to start. And more fun than installing an app to do it for you!

Comment: great and simple idea! But I guess there's no way of opening slingshot from the icon (eg. from the bottom if the dock is there), right?

Comment: In theory you should. I meant to test this out yesterday but didn't have time. If you create the .desktop file you'll be able to find it in the Slingshot menu - right click on it and select Add to Dock.  Sorry I left that bit out 

Comment: OK I just tested it out and while it does launch the Slingshot menu, it unfortunately launches it from it's normal top left locations. I assume you want it to pop up from the icon itself.

Comment: I'm not the one who opened the question, so I have no idea what are his needs. I was just interested in the topic and thats a possible problem, yes.

Comment: I noticed that after I wrote it. Also noticed this question was from back in May. haha I'm always looking for a way to enable/disable functions via shell scripts. Seems to work best for me. Plus it's more fun to create the solution yourself you know.

Comment: nice. **whoever is down-voting around here has no idea what voting here means**.

Comment: as for an icon, this could do: http://www.stickpng.com/es/img/objetos/tirachinas/tirachinas-zelda

Answer (score 0):

AppEditor will be your friend. You can have it from AppCenter. Easy to use. After first start of the program you can keep your new app on your dock.